# Lua script in Aegisub? I don't understand it

Tags: lua

I'm trying to make vertical karaoke kanji with furigana in Aegisub which uses lua script. I didn't write the code as I state here, I'm not advanced enough to write codes yet, but I can edit the effects at least. - http://forum.aegisub.org/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=66245&p=90280#p90280
My file and other needed info regarding my topic can be found there as well. 
I'm very confused at the moment as I can't figure out how to make the code so that the subtitles don't spin and keep their current effect... Also, the code that the person gave me, doesn't work. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!